# NoClassDefFoundError even though .jar file is included

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, war, jnotify

Hi I have a weird problem where when I run my webapp, I get a NoClassDefFoundError

But when I check in Eclipse, I find the .jar file (Jnotify.jar) and it shows all the classes. 
Same case when I import the .war file of my webapp I see the classes in the dependencies.

What could be my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not looking in the right pace. Please post how you run your webapp.

Comment: Is it showing in class path? have you checked your Jnotify.jar included in application class path?

Comment: I launch my webapp using tomcat. It does show correctly in the application class path

Comment: Are you placing it in the correct place (i.e. WEB-INF/lib)?

Comment: yea its in there. Apparently JNotify comes with .dll files, I read that theres somewhere you have to put them but I can't figure out where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing the error:

JNotify has specific Library DLL, I was placing them corectly in java.library.path but the problem is Tomcat doesn't look for those libraries unless the corresponding .jar files are in Tomcat/lib.

So adding my jnotify.jar to tomcat/lib fixed my problems.